# get the next element with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some elements like

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <p><input type="checkbox" />text</p>
    <p>special text</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" />text</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" />text</p>
</div>
```

My aim is to check the input-boxes below the 'special text'.
Therefore I created a variable findText to find 'special text'

```
var findText = $("#myDiv:contains('special text')");
```

I'm checking whether 'special text' exists and if so, I want the next input elements to be checked. `.nextAll()` unfortunately just gets the following siblings. But how can I call the next elements?

```
 var findText = $("#myDiv:contains('special text')");

    if(findText.length > 0) {
      findText.nextAll("input").attr("checked",true)
    }
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: So you want the checkbox immediately after `special text` to be checked?

Comment: Yes. I want all checkboxes checked after special text.

Comment: and if `nextAll` is not enough for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30089307/274502

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextAll` with a [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) should do it:

```
findText.nextAll("p").find("input").attr("checked",true);
```

That finds the following paragraphs, and their descendant inputs. (Or use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) rather than `find` if the inputs are guaranteed to be immediate children of the paragraphs.)

...but I think your selector for `findText` is incorrect, try:

```
var findText = $("#myDiv p:contains('special text')");
//                      ^^^---- change here
```

Putting that all together:

```
var findText = $("#myDiv p:contains('special text')");

if(findText.length > 0) {
  findText.nextAll("p").find("input").attr("checked",true)
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/efugo4)

Separately, you might consider limiting the search to just checkboxes with jQuery's custom [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector:

```
var findText = $("#myDiv p:contains('special text')");

if(findText.length > 0) {
  findText.nextAll("p").find(":checkbox").attr("checked",true)
  //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^-- Change here
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/efugo4/2)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
$("#myDiv p:contains('special text')").next().children('input').prop('checked',true);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HVSyE/3/

Edit: if you want all the checkboxes after the text to be checked, then:

```
$("#myDiv p:contains('special text')").nextAll('p').children('input').prop('checked',true);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HVSyE/4/

Comment: That only finds the one next paragraph. His use of `nextAll` (and his use of the plural in the text of the question) suggests he wants all of them.