# Find the next element that comes later in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Probably better in javascript, but this can sure include jQuery, or any such library.

I want to find the first `.next` in the example below.

There are a lot of answers to similar questions that suggest `nextAll` or `siblings`... Both are useless here:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.result').text(
    $('.origin').nextAll('.next').text()
      || $('.origin').siblings('.next').text()
      || 'both failed'
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="whatever">
  <p class="result"></p>
  <p class="origin">1</p>
</div>
<p class="next">2</p>
<p class="next">3</p>
```

Also, what'd be the most compatible (browser and library wise) and most performatic (speed and less lines of code) way to do it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902127/274502) by  [@mrtsherman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510314/mrtsherman), I wrote this more complete solution and tested it to work on Chrome and Safari:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.result').text(
    $('.origin').below('.next').text()
  );
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.below = function(sel) {
    var $result = $(sel).first();
    if ($result.length <= 0) {
      return $result;
    }
    $result = [];
    var thisIndex = $('*').index($(this));
    var selIndex = Number.MAX_VALUE; // Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is not yet fully supported
    $(sel).each(function(i, val) {
      var valIndex = $('*').index($(val));
      if (thisIndex < valIndex && valIndex < selIndex) {
        selIndex = valIndex;
        $result = $(val);
      }
    });
    return $result;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="whatever">
  <p class="result"></p>
  <p class="origin">1</p>
</div>
<p class="next">2</p>
<p class="next">3</p>
```

I will probably [try to submit a PR for this on jQuery lib](http://contribute.jquery.org/commits-and-pull-requests/), because *I believe*...

**This should be a core method on jQuery**! :P

---

In fact, [I just ran a very simplistic test on this](http://jsperf.com/jquery-below), and it performed even better than `nextAll` for this simple example. Almost twice as fast! :o

Answer (score 2):

If you can use IE9+ you can try `compareDocumentPosition()`. A simple jQuery plugin would look something like this:

```
$.fn.below = function(selector) {
  var el = this[0],
      compare = $(selector),
      nextEl;

  compare.each(function(i, item) {
    var result = el.compareDocumentPosition(item);
    // get the first one that appears below `this`
    if (result === 4) {
      nextEl = $(item);
      return false;
    }
  });
  return nextEl || $();
};
```

This could probably be cleaned up/simplified a bit. But it works nicely. Here is a codpen:

http://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/QbjZmr?editors=101

`compareDocumentPosition()` returns a number which has the following meaning:

(where `p1.compareDocumentPosition(p2)`)

1: No relationship, the two nodes do not belong to the same document.

2: The first node (p1) is positioned after the second node (p2).

4: The first node (p1) is positioned before the second node (p2).

8: The first node (p1) is positioned inside the second node (p2).

16: The second node (p2) is positioned inside the first node (p1).

32: No relationship, or the two nodes are two attributes on the same element.

*Note the above was just copied from:* http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_comparedocumentposition.asp

Comment: Awesome, that's even a [little bit more performatic](http://jsperf.com/jquery-below) on my test than my code! Although just a little bit. :P So the universal selector solution there is still better if you need compatibility (so I'll still claim it's generally better). Also, maybe I could improve its performance by replacing `.each` with javascript native `for`, I read some places... But I do like much better how this looks much simpler, and it's somehow already implemented. :)

Comment: cool yeah, totally agree about compatibility - if you feel like it, you could check if `compareDocumentPosition` is defined, and use it if it is - otherwise use your solution. But if its a really small performance difference may not make sense... :D